# TypeScript CRUD route

Tags: node.js

I am working on a CRUD implementation for a user.

I have a user class, users consists of first name, username, surname and password:

```
class User {
    public readonly uName: string;
    public fName: string;
    public lName: string;
    private password: string;

    constructor(fName: string, lName: string, uName: string, password: string) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.uName = uName;
        this.password = password;
    }
}

let Users: User[];
Users = [];
```

I already have something that compares entered data and inserts it:

```
router.post("/nutzer?", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)=>{
    const fName: string = req.body.fName;
    const lName: string = req.body.lName;
    const uName: string = req.body.uName;
    const password: string = req.body.password;

    if (fName && lName && uName && password) {
        let neuerUser = new User(fName, lName, uName, password);
        Users.push(neuerUser);
        res.status(201);
        res.send({
            neuerUser,
            message: 'Nutzer erstellt'
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400);
        res.send({
            message: 'alle Felder müssen ausgefüllt sein',
        });
    }
});
```

However, I have a problem with the read/update/delete

### Read

The route spits out only the first one from the array and does not look for the current one that I have in the url

```
router.get('/nutzer/:uName?', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const uName: string = req.params.uName;
    for (let User of Users) {
        if (User.uName === uName) {
           res.status(200);
               res.send({
                User,
                message: 'Nutzer gefunden',
            });
        }else{
            res.status(404);
                res.send({
                message: 'Nutzer nicht gefunden',
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Edit user PUT does not work from front to back.

```
router.put('/nutzer/:uName?', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)=> {
    const uName: string = req.params.userId;
    const fName: string = req.body.firstName;
    const lName: string = req.body.lastName;

    if (fName && lName) {
        for (const user of Users) {
            if (uName === req.params.uName) {
                user.fName = fName;
                user.lName = lName;
                res.status(200);
                res.send({
                    user,
                    message: `Nutzer erfolgreich ugedatet ${user.fName} ${user.lName}`
                });
            }else{
                res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Nutzerupdate nicht gefunden'
            });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Delete user DELETE only deletes the first user in the array

```
router.delete("/nutzer/:uName?", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
                    const uName: string = req.params.uName;
                    if (uName === req.params.uName) {
                        //nicht
                        Users.splice(Users.indexOf(uName), 1);
                        res.status(200);
                        res.send({
                            message: 'Benutzer gelöscht'});
                    } else {
                        res.status(404);
                        res.send({
                            message: 'Benutzer nicht gefunden'});
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hello there, welcome to stack overflow! Can you please post your problem in english?

Comment: Need help with CRUD implementation for a user..
User class with array: consists of first name, username, surname and password. Create works compares entered data and inserts it

I have problems with Read, update, Delete

// READ The route spits out only the first one from the array and does not look for the current one that I have in the url.
// edit user PUT does not work from front to back urgently pls
// delete user DELETE deletes only the first user in the array

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're iterating on your array and responding every time. Instead, you should do read/update/delete operations on your array *and then* respond once. This, or something closely similar, should work better

```
// READ
router.get('/nutzer/:uName?', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const uName: string = req.params.uName;
    const found = Users.find(user => user.uName === uName);
    if (found) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send({ User: found, message: 'Nutzer gefunden' });
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        res.send({ message: 'Nutzer nicht gefunden' });
    }
});

// UPDATE
router.put('/nutzer/:uName?', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)=> {
    const uName: string = req.params.userId;
    const fName: string = req.body.firstName;
    const lName: string = req.body.lastName;

    let found = null;
    if (fName && lName) {
        for (const user of Users) {
            if (uName === req.params.uName) {
                found = user;
                user.fName = fName;
                user.lName = lName;
                res.status(200);
            }
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send({ user: found, message: `Nutzer erfolgreich ugedatet ${user.fName} ${user.lName}` });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nutzerupdate nicht gefunden' });
    }
});
```

For your delete, you mess up differently, because you're not even finding the right element. This should work

```
// DELETE
router.delete("/nutzer/:uName?", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const uName: string = req.params.uName;
    const index = Users.findIndex(user => user.uName === uName);
    if (index == -1) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send({ message: 'Benutzer nicht gefunden' });
    } else {
        Users.splice(index, 1);
        res.status(200);
        res.send({ message: 'Benutzer gelöscht'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is broken:

```
for (let User of Users) {
   if (User.uName === uName) {
     res.status(200);
     res.send({
       User,
       message: 'Nutzer gefunden',
     });
   } else {
     res.status(404);
     res.send({
       message: 'Nutzer nicht gefunden',
     });
   }
 }
```

The loop compares the first element of your array and then sends the response to the client: 200 if the first element matched `uName` else 404.

Instead use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find a certain user in your array:

```
const user = users.find(value => value.uName === uName);

if (user) {
  // User found
} else {
  // Not found
}

// Or just
return user
  ? res.json({ user, message: '...' }).status(200)
  : res.json({ message: '...' }).status(404);
```